# Can not load AJAX data from the server in tree view plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, plugins, treeview

There are many jQuery plugins for creating a checkbox tree view, but I can't find documentation of loading data from a server using AJAX. For example [this link](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Multi-Selectable-Tree-Structure-Tree-Multiselect.html).

I want something like this:

```
$('#CheckBoxTree').LoadTreeView('/WebHandler/GetData.ashx') {
}
```

Or using classic ajax format

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/WebHandler/Data.ashx',
    async: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { proname: 'pro' },
    success: function (dataa) {
        $('#CheckBoxTree').SetData(dataa)
    });
}
});
```

I tried using second technique on one plugin but it failed. I did this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/WebHandler/GetPlotData.ashx',
    async: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { proname: 'province' },
    success: function (dataa) {
        debugger
        $('#tree-container').highCheckTree({                    
            data: dataa
        });
    }
});
```

Kindly help me so that I can continue my work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I used DynaTree,
it has a lot of documentation. Here is a [Link](https://github.com/mar10/dynatree)
 it has a lot of old versions which are comparable with old jquery.

i just had to write this much code.

```
    $("#tree").dynatree({
        checkbox: true,
        autoCollapse: false,
        activeVisible: true,
        persist: true,
      //  selectMode: 1,
        onLazyRead: function (node) {           
            node.appendAjax({
                url: "/WebHandler/GetPlotData.ashx",
                data: {
                    "proname": "district",
                     "key":node.data.key,
                    "mode": "all"
                }
            });
        },
        initAjax: {
            url: "/WebHandler/GetPlotData.ashx",
            data: {proname: "province", // Optional arguments to append to the url
                mode: "all"
            }
        },

  });
```